# Laravel Validation class for update method

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem when I try to modify existing data in the database. It is a product category that has a unique slug. When I create a new category I check if there is a `slug` in the database. When I want to change the existing category, I get an error that the `slug` is already taken.

I found some examples on StackOveflow but nothing can solve my problem.

---

### Structure

##### `category table`

```
category_id, parent_id, status, created_at, ...
--------------------------------------------------
```

##### `category_details`

```
category_id, name, slug, description, ....
--------------------------------------------------
```

**Models**

```php
class Category extends Model
{
  use HasFactory;
    
  protected $table = "category";
  protected $fillable = [
    'parent_id',
    'image',
    'status',
    'show_in_menu',
    'sort_order'
  ];

  /**
   * Category details table
   */
  public function details()
  {
    return $this->hasOne(CategoryDetails::class, 'category_id', 'id');
  }
}
```

```php
class CategoryDetails extends Model
{
  use HasFactory;
    
  protected $primaryKey = 'category_id';
  protected $fillable = [
    'category_id',
    'name',
    'slug',
    'description',
    'description_below',
    'meta_title',
    'meta_description'
  ];
}
```

##### Form Request Class

```php
public function rules(): array
{
  if($this->isMethod('post')) {
    return [
      'name' => 'required',
      'slug' => 'required|unique:category_details',
      'meta_title' => 'required|max:60',
      'meta_description' => 'max:160',
      'status' => 'accepted'
    ];
  }

  if($this->isMethod('patch')) {
    return [
      'name' => 'required',
      'slug' =>'required|unique:category_details,slug,'.$this->category_id,
      'meta_title' => 'required|max:60',
      'meta_description' => 'max:160',
    ];
  }
}
```

##### Controller

```php
public function update(CategoryRequest $request, int $id)
{
  $category = Category::find($id)->first();
    
  $category->update([
    'parent_id' => $request->input('parent_id'),
    'image' =>  '',
    'status' => $request->input('status') == 'on' ? 1 : 0,
    'sort_order' => $request->input('sort_order')
  ]);
    
  $category->details->update([
    'category_id' => $id,
    'name' => $request->input('name'),
    'slug' => $request->input('slug'),
    'description' => $request->input('description'),
    'meta_title' => $request->input('meta_title'),
    'meta_description' => $request->input('meta_description')
  ]);
    
  return redirect()
    ->route('categories.edit', $category->id)
    ->with('success', "Category {$category->details->name} successfully updated");
}
```

---

### Error Message

I received an error during the update event.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where
> clause'

```sql
select
  count(*) as aggregate
from `category_details`
where `slug` = dekubitus2
  and `id` <>
```

Comment: Do you have the ID column on the tables for the auto-incrementing identifier?

Comment: in `category_details` i dont have column with `AI` only `category_id` PK

Comment: Pass the idColumn as well to the rule. `unique:category_details, slug, ' . $this->category_id . ', category_id',`

Comment: @Ivan, Could you provide the complete SQL that is executed during the update? Additionally, the models are missing information on how you connected the two tables. ....and, the update function itself is missing. The request passes through the authentication, as the update SQL script is executed. Therefore, I would not look for the error in the rules.

Comment: @linktoahref when do that i get the some validation message `The slug has already been taken.`

Comment: @MarwaneEzzaze i modify table and add AI column but the some. Validation not allow me to save changes

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in this line:

```
 'slug' =>'required|unique:category_details,slug,'.$this->category_id,
```

for the [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-unique)  validation rule, you should provide column name so Laravel check the DB existence.
but if you did not pass that parameter, it be by default 'id':
change that line to:

```
'slug' => [
         'required',
          Rule::unique('category_details', 'slug')->ignore($this->category, 'category_id'),
            ],
```

Comment: i tested your code and is the some problem. But what i try and that work `required|unique:category_details,slug,12` i manualy put id of the row `12`. That is AI column id from `category_details` table. That is relation `hasOne`! When i pass `$this->id` not work, when i pass `$this->category_id` also not work! I think they need id of the row but that row id i try to get to access with relation `$this->details->id` and i get `Attempt to read property "id" on null`. But there is `ID (PK, AI)`

Comment: can you provide the route?

Comment: Its resources route.  `categories.index,store, show, edit, update, destroy`,  `Route::resource('admin/catalog/categories', CategoryController::class);`

Comment: well , based in your info, then you should use $this->category like the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

#### -- Reflection to your SQL code

I don't understand it... what generated this SQL code?

> ```sql
> select
>   count(*) as aggregate
> from `category_details`
> where `slug` = dekubitus2
>   and `id` <>
> ```

This SQL code tried found `category_details.id` but it's not exists on your structure. You used `category_details.category_id` as primary key on `category_details` table, and you used it for relationship too.

#### 1.) One To One Relationship on Laravel

> [`hasOne()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)
>
> ```php
> return $this->hasOne(Phone::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
> ```

###### Your relation

```php
// From Category (local) To CategoryDetails (foreign)
return $this->hasOne(CategoryDetails::class, 'category_id', 'id');
```

You used `category_details.category_id` as foreign_key, and used `category.id` as local_key. However you don't declared `category.id` column on your database.

###### `category` table structure

> ```
> category_id, parent_id, status, created_at, ...
> ```

If I want follow your structure, need declare `category.category_key` as local_key on your relationship.

#### Solution # 1

Need declare your relationship with exists columns.

```php
// Category.php Model

public function details()
{
  return $this->hasOne(CategoryDetails::class, 'category_id', 'category_id');
  //      /\                  /\                    /\             /\
  //   local_model        foreign_model         foreign_key     local_key
}
```

and need declare your primary key name on your Category model:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'category_id';
```

#### Solution # 2

Or can rename your `category.category_id` column to `category.id`. If will choise it, then your relation perfect what here declared.

---

#### 2.) Update with One To One Relationship on Laravel

```php
public function update(CategoryRequest $request, int $id)
{
  // Get category by id
  $category = Category::find($id)->firstOrFail();
  // Use ->firstOrFail() instead of ->first()
  // because if category cannot found, then don't need run update
    
  // Update category (thats ok)
  $category->update([
    'parent_id' => $request->input('parent_id'),
    'image' =>  '',
    'status' => $request->input('status') == 'on' ? 1 : 0,
    'sort_order' => $request->input('sort_order')
  ]);
    
  // Update category's details
  // Can try use ->updateOrCreate() instead of ->update()
  // - I don't know your full logic, so thats just my idea.. if details not exists when you tried update them
  $category->details->updateOrCreate([
    /* 'category_id' => $id, */ /* dont't need declare category_id, because used relationship for update running */
    'name' => $request->input('name'),
    'slug' => $request->input('slug'),
    'description' => $request->input('description'),
    'meta_title' => $request->input('meta_title'),
    'meta_description' => $request->input('meta_description')
  ]);
  
  // Redirect
  return redirect()
    ->route('categories.edit', $category->id)
    ->with('success', "Category {$category->details->name} successfully updated");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

return [
    'slug' => ['required', Rule::unique('category_details')->ignore($this->category_id)],
];
```

Answer (score -1):

Your model for Category, change the ID to the category_id, because from what you have mentioned above, there's no ID in the table structure :

```
class Category extends Model
{
  use HasFactory;
    
  protected $table = "category";
  protected $fillable = [
    'parent_id',
    'image',
    'status',
    'show_in_menu',
    'sort_order'
  ];

  /**
   * Category details table
   */
  public function details()
  {
    return $this->hasOne(CategoryDetails::class, 'category_id', 'category_id');
  }
}
```